# ¿Por qué fue aprobada esta edición?

Tags: discusión, ediciones-sugeridas

Mi duda concierne la pregunta siguiente: [¿Por qué no me da el número anterior?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29506/por-qu%C3%A9-no-me-da-el-n%C3%BAmero-anterior).

Un usuario propuso la edición siguiente: https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/29506/5, efectivamente cambiando el error reportado por OP en su pregunta.

En mi opinión, eso no se debería hacer, ya que solo OP puede decirnos cuál es su problema, nadie más. Y si el error no corresponde, pues probablemente es porque OP no puso el código que reproduce su error, y debería corregir el código.

Entonces, ¿por qué se aprobó el cambio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay casos concretos en los que una edición sustancial de la pregunta *puede* ser correcta, pero son casos concretos:

- Cuándo el autor de la pregunta añade su código/error en comentarios y es nuevo en el sitio. En este caso es aceptable editar su pregunta pero siempre añadiendo en el comentario de la edición el por qué se ha realizado ese cambio que es sustancial.
- Cúando en el chat o en una respuesta a la pregunta se añade más información y se puede hacer lo mismo que en el punto anterior.

En el resto de casos esto no es correcto.

En este caso concreto esta edición con el error no parece proceder ni de un comentario ni del chat y en la información de la edición no se especifica nada por lo que lo correcto en estos casos es **rechazar la edición**.

Cuándo aún así la edición es aceptada hay varias opciones:

- Si uno está 100% seguro que no cumple los criterios y es una mala edición, puede hacer una reversión (si tiene la suficiente reputación). Si no se tiene suficiente reputación es recomendable hacer un custom flag para que los moderadores lo revisemos. Es mejor evitar entrar en una guerra de ediciones por lo que no es recomendable re-editar la pregunta si no se tiene la reputación para hacer la reversión.
- Si no queda muy claro, se puede dejar un comentario preguntando el por qué de la edición o bien publicarlo en meta (este caso) para intentar aclararlo.